# Linq-to-SQL: binding ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm struggling for quite some time now with binding my `ListView` to a table. I've read various solutions, but I keep running into trouble.

I have 2 database tables: `Customer`s and `Product`s. For each `Customer` there is a list of `Product`s.

In my first attempt I bind to the generated Linq-to-SQL code. That means I binding immediately to `Customer.Products`. But since this is of type `System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Product>`, I don't get notified when items are added to/removed from the database.

So I extended the generated code by adding a method to `Customer` that wraps the returned `System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Product>` in an `ObservableCollection` (as adviced by various blogs)

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> ObservableProducts
{
    get
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Product>(Products);
    }
}
```

But now I cannot add anything to the collection. When I call `ObservableProducts.Add()` nothing is added..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` is *not* a view on an underlying collection - it is a collection in its own right. When you pass the `List` to the `ObservableCollection`, the items in the `List` are copied to the `ObservableCollection`.

So your item *is* being added, but only to the `ObservableCollection` - not the underlying `List` you passed to it.

Options for moving forward include:

- Using an `ObservableCollection` in your data layer. Convert the entity list to an `ObservableCollection` straight away and use that throughout the application.
- Listening for changes to the `ObservableCollection` and applying those changes to the underlying `List`.
- Write an implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` that *is* a view on an underlying collection. This can only work one-way (OC->List but not List->OC) and gets tricky if you have a multithreaded application.